# What's the reason I'm getting the "SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: leaked its continuation" error here?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I'm learning new concurrency features right now and I'm making a wrapper for StoreKit 1 that uses async methods.
I have basically two main methods, one is for purchasing, the other for restoring transactions:

```
public func purchase(product: IAPProduct) async throws {

    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        _purchase(product: product) { error in
            if let error = error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}

public func restorePurchases() async throws -> [IAPProduct] {
    
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        _restorePurchases { result in
            continuation.resume(with: result)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both of them are calling private methods which use completion handlers:

```
func _purchase(product: SKProduct, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    
    guard canMakePurchases else {
        completion(IAPError.purchasesDisabled)
        return
    }
    isRestoringPurchases = false
    onProductPurchase = completion
    
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    queue.add(payment)
    
    print("Product to purchase: \(product.localizedTitle)")
}

func _restorePurchases(completion: @escaping (Result<[IAPProduct], Error>) -> Void) {
    isRestoringPurchases = true
    
    onPurchasesRestore = completion
    queue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    
    print("Restoring purchases...")
}
```

The rest of the class code is irrelevant I think, in proper delegate methods I'm calling the `onProductPurchase` or `onPurchasesRestore` which properly causes the continuations to resume.
But I'm getting error in the purchase method and purchase method only.

> SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: purchase(product:) leaked its
> continuation!

The restore method doesn't throw any error
Am I using `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` wrong? Is it reserved only for async methods that return something? As you can see basically the only difference between purchase and restore methods is that the latter is returning an array of objects while the other is Void

Comment: Does StoreKit not have built-in async methods? I would have totally expected those to exist.

Comment: @Sweeper that’s not the point of the question. I know they exist, but I need to support iOS 13 and want to learn something along the way.